# How to model social structure in SIR models

Tags: population-dynamics, epidemiology, infectious-diseases, sociality

*I refer to J.H. Jones' [Notes on R<sub>0</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UUmy.png).*

*More details in this question at Mathematics SE: [How does the reproduction number depend on characteristics of the physical contact graph of a population?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682077/how-does-the-reproduction-number-depend-on-characteristics-of-the-physical-conta)*

---

The basic SIR model - as described in Jones' Notes - considers three factors that make up the reproduction number:

- $\tau$ = the transmissibility (i.e., probability of infection given contact between a susceptible and infected individual)
- $\overline{c}$ = the average rate of contact between susceptible and infected individuals
- $d$ = the duration of infectiousness

The (basic) reproduction number then is

$$R_0 = \tau \cdot \overline{c} \cdot d$$

I wonder how to model social structure in a SIR model, which might influence both transmissibilty $\tau$ and average rate of contact $\overline{c}$ and thus the reproduction number $R_0$, resp. the infection rate $\beta = \tau \cdot \overline{c} = R_0 / d$.

Specifically I wonder which "control parameters" appropriately describe the social structure of a population and may influence transmissibilty $\tau$ and average rate of contact $\overline{c}$ in a specific and comprehensible way.

Among these parameters may be:

- typical (mean) numbers of household members and acquainted persons
- typical ratio of shared acquaintances
- typical numbers of strangers one meets (e.g. per month)
- typical times of contact to household members, acquainted persons, and strangers
- the amount of persons with outstanding many social contacts, better: the standard deviation of the contact rate
- the accepted physical distance to family members, acquainted persons and strangers
  [image]<sup>([source](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/873645.sorokowska_et_al_2017.pdf))</sup>

I am looking for approaches that let go such parameters into the infection rate $\beta = \tau \cdot \overline{c}$ in a quantitative way.